# Inject into mapper

Tags: hadoop, testing

I use Random class in my Mapper for some initialization. Now I want to perform integration tests on the processing pipeline and I was wondering is there a way to inject a mock of Random into Mapper during integration tests?

The only other way I see it to specify seed for the Random through Configuration in the Mapper.

Is there a way to do it using the first approach (injection), or should I stick to the other one (passing seed through Configuration)?

Comment: You might be able to use Mockito to inject an implementation of Random.

Comment: @BinaryNerd But how can I do that since I'm not the one instantiating the Mapper, but this is is done by Hadoop itself?

Comment: Ah, sorry i was thinking unit test. For actual running on a cluster setting stuff using the configuration would be the way i would go.